# syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Tags: syntax, mysqli

I'm a total newbie when it comes to php and mysql/mysqli. I have this code and I get a PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /home/byeroman/public_html/register.php on line 17. Here's the code:

```
$stmt = mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=? LIMIT 1" or die($db->error()));
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
        $count=$stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        if($count>0) exit();
```

what's wrong? thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

That's silly syntax issue, you just forgot closing brace.
To make such things less possible and also to make your code readable, divide your statements into separate lines:

```
$sql  = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error()));
```

You also need to make your mind which variable you're using ($mysqli or $db)
Also, `num_rows()` is wrong function to use, you need regular `fetch` instead.

By the way, consider to use some database abstraction library. It can make your life a lot easier and code - shorter, like this (it replaces ALL your code, mind you):

```
$num = $db->getOne("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=?",$username);
if($num) { ...
```